# Bokeh tooltips' arguments for Bar chart

Tags: bokeh

I'm plotting a stacked bar graph of a dataframe df that contains 3 columns: x, y and group_by. Each bar represents counts of different types of documents. When I hover over them 'type' and 'group_by' are displayed without problem, but 'count' isn't. I tried unsuccessfully '$y', and defining "values='y'" differently. I don`t fully understand this syntax... Thanks for your help.

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar
from bokeh.charts.attributes import cat

bar = Bar(df,
      values='y', 
      label=cat(columns='x', sort=False),
      stack=cat(columns='group_by', sort=False),
      tooltips=[('type', '@group_by'), ('app', '@x'), ('count', '@y')])
```

[image]

Comment: i went with plot.ly, guys. But i still want to know how to do this in Bokeh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data tooltips in Bokeh don't show data, showing '???' instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022985/data-tooltips-in-bokeh-dont-show-data-showing-instead)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I found the answer in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2965). It seems like the height of the stacked section of a bar is called *height*. 
Try this out (untested):

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar
from bokeh.charts.attributes import cat

bar = Bar(
    df,
    values='y', 
    label=cat(columns='x', sort=False),
    stack=cat(columns='group_by', sort=False),
    tooltips=[
        ('type', '@group_by'), 
        ('app', '@x'), 
        ('count', '@height'),
    ],
)
```