# Bokek Hover Tool Displaying Incorrectly | Python

Tags: python, graph, data-visualization, bokeh

I have the following dataframe:

```
Date                   Impressions  Link_Clicks
2017-05-29 00-00-00    1,492,046    8,093
2017-06-05 00-00-00    845,012      4,864
2017-06-12 00-00-00    1,167,100    6,897
2017-06-19 00-00-00    895,781      4,472
2017-06-26 00-00-00    1,037,839    9,518
2017-07-03 00-00-00    1,139,060    9,668
2017-07-10 00-00-00    1,235,760    9,268
2017-07-17 00-00-00    1,200,906    7,989
2017-07-24 00-00-00    1,214,534    6,991
2017-07-31 00-00-00    1,434,225    7,311
2017-08-07 00-00-00    557,393      2,908
```

I am trying to visualise this using Bokeh which I've managed to do successfully, however when implementing the hover-tool, it returns the number divided specifically by 2. Is this a bug?

Libraries used:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, push_notebook
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, curdoc
output_notebook()
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, DatetimeTickFormatter, DataRange1d, CustomJS, Plot, LinearAxis, Grid
from bokeh.charts import Bar, BoxPlot, Donut, HeatMap, Histogram, Line, Scatter, TimeSeries
```

My code can be found below:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    desc = bar_df.index,
    y = bar_df["Link_Clicks"],
))

p = Bar(bar_df, label=bar_df.index, values="Link_Clicks", width=1, source=source, agg='sum',
       line_color="white", plot_width=900, plot_height=400, bar_width=0.9, legend=None, toolbar_location="right")

p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("Link_Clicks", "@y{1.11}"),
                                ("Date", "@index")]))

p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 45

show(p)
```

NOTE: if you try and replicate this, dates for Bokeh can't be in DateTime format; only strings.

To quickly convert: `df["Date"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace(':','-'))`

[image]

When hovering over, you can see this is divided perfectly by 2 which is strange. I have tried multiplying y*2 under ColumnDataSource and within the Hover Tool, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of bokeh are you using? `bokeh.charts` has been deprecated and is no longer maintained, so if it is a bug it's probably worth reformatting your code for the latest release.

Comment: Hi Toby - you are correct. I have made the necessary changes. I will post now. Appreciate you helping me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking into this, I have solved it thanks to toby pointing me in the right direction. I tried it with a simpler data-set, but it works with everything I've tried. See below:

**Data:**

```
bokeh_bar = df.groupby(["Audience"], as_index=False)["Impressions"].sum()

Index       Audience    Impressions
0           Core        23725548
1           Homepage    14163811
2           LAL_10%     18277859
3           LAL_3%      14879857
4           Page_1      4406266
```

**Code:**

```
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(audience=list(bokeh_bar["Audience"]), 
                                    impressions=list(bokeh_bar["Impressions"]), 
                                    color=Spectral6))

p = figure(x_range=list(bokeh_bar["Audience"]), plot_width=900, plot_height=300, title="Impressions by Audience",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x='audience', top='impressions', width=0.9, color='color', 
       legend="audience", source=source)

p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("Audience", "@audience"), ("Impressions", "@impressions")]))

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"
p.legend.location = ('top_right')
p.legend.label_text_font_size = '8pt'

show(p)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Hopefully, that's helped. The hover tool returns the correct figures too.