# Hover ToolTip Not Working for Bokeh visualization of Networkx Graph

Tags: pandas, graph, networkx, bokeh

I'm trying to make graph using Networkx and rendering the graph using Bokeh. Everything seems to be working except for the hover tooltip I've consulted [Data tooltips in Bokeh don't show data, showing '???' instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022985/data-tooltips-in-bokeh-dont-show-data-showing-instead), [Bokeh hover tooltip not displaying all data - Ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226119/bokeh-hover-tooltip-not-displaying-all-data-ipython-notebook), and read the documentation on ColumnDataSource, but i still can't figure out why tooltips won't render labels from one of the columns of my dataframe.

Below is a overly simplified of the data from an excel file, which I've been playing around with.

```
group    subtopic    code
fruit    grapes      110A
fruit    apple       110B
meat     pork        220A
meat     chicken     220B
meat     duck        220C
vegetable lettuce    300A
vegetable tomato     310A
vegetable asparagus  320A
```

I tried running the following code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file1, sheetname = 'Sheet3')

reshape = []

for i, j, in df.iterrows():
    for _, k in df.iterrows():
        if (j['code'] == k['code']):
            pass
        elif j['group'] == 'nan':
            reshape.append({'code1':j['code'],
                       'code2': j['code'],
                       'group': 'None'})
        elif (j['group'] == k['group']):
            reshape.append({'code1': j['code'],
                       'code2': k['code'],
                       'group': j['group']})
        else:
            pass
df1 = pd.DataFrame(reshape)

g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, source='code1', target='code2', edge_attr = True)


source = ColumnDataSource(df)

TOOLTIPS = [("type", "@group"),("code", "@code1")]

plot = Plot(x_range = Range1d(-1.1,1.1), y_range = Range1d(-1.1,1.1))
plot.title.text = 'Bokeh Plot'

plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips = TOOLTIPS), TapTool(), BoxSelectTool(), 
 WheelZoomTool())

graph_renderer = from_networkx(g, nx.spring_layout, scale = 1, center = (0,0))

# manipulating nodes
graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size = 15, fill_color = Spectral4[0])
graph_renderer.node_renderer.selection_glyph = Circle(size = 15, fill_color = 
 Spectral4[2])
graph_renderer.node_renderer.hover_glyph = Circle(size = 15, fill_color = 
 Spectral4[1])

# manipulating edges
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color = '#CCCCCC', line_alpha = 
 .5, line_width = 5)
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.selection_glyph = MultiLine(line_color = Spectral4[2], 
 line_width = 5)
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.hover_glyph = MultiLine(line_color = Spectral4[1], 
 line_width = 5)

graph_renderer.selection_policy = NodesAndLinkedEdges()
graph_renderer.inspection_policy = EdgesAndLinkedNodes()

plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)

output_notebook()
show(plot)
```

After I run the script, i get the following:

[image: screenshit]
The group column label correctly displays, but not the subtopic. I'd appreciate any ideas or pointers.

Comment: What version of Bokeh?

Comment: i'm running 1.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a `ColumnDataSource` but then not actually using it for anything. A CDS has no effect simply by virtue of having been created, it has to be configured to drive a glyph or table, etc. The hover tool uses the data source the glyph has configured, which in this case is set up by `from_networkx`. You can access the data source for the node renderers, to add whatever additional columns you want to it (e.g. to use for a hover tool):

```
graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source.data['code1'] = # your data here
```

Comment: got it! i think i understand now. graph_rendered.node_renderer.data_source.data is a dict with and entry "index" with a list of node names from g, my networkx object. So really in my tooltips, the following could've worked TOOLTIPS = [('code', '@index')] and like you said i would use add values as necessary to the dict if i wanted additional values to be displayed on hover.

Comment: @imstuck Your comment here was exactly what I wanted to learn.  Thanks!